# Как запретить чтоб никто не писал моему telegram боту кроме меня?

Tags: python, парсер, telegram-bot, api, telebot

Сделал телеграмм бот парсера, хочу его добавить в беседу. В беседе, как я знаю, можно ограничить, чтобы боту не писали. Ну они могут ему в личку написать. Как сделать так, чтоб кроме меня никто не мог запускать бота?

Comment: есть возможность слушать сообщения конкретно от какого то пользователя, поищите тему по ключевому слову telebot chat_id

Comment: @АндрійПанчій Спасибо большое, а могу ли я  узнать свой и условие прописать если это мой id будет ,то запускай функцию если нет ,то не запускай?

Comment: да конешно, вы можете настроить так что б бот отправлял только вам сообщения и всех игнорировал, если это нужно

Comment: @АндрійПанчій Спасибо очень помогли) у меня 11 репутация так бы поставил лайк или как тут называется

Comment: @ГорМанучарян, лучше напишите ответ к своему вопросу с примером кода. Так вы поможете другим людям, которые столкнутся с этой проблемой.

Comment: @КириллМалышев Хорошо как сделаю кину, и отмечу вас чтобы вы зашли и увидели

Comment: @КириллМалышев ***

Comment: @ГорМанучарян, отлично!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел [отсюда](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#restrict-access-to-a-handler-decorator) фрагмент кода

```
from functools import wraps

LIST_OF_ADMINS = [12345678, 87654321]

def restricted(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(update, context, *args, **kwargs):
        user_id = update.effective_user.id
        if user_id not in LIST_OF_ADMINS:
            print("Unauthorized access denied for {}.".format(user_id))
            return
        return func(update, context, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```